# Magento onepage design

Tags: magento, checkout

I've got some trouble with the Magento shop. On the checkout onepage, right at the bottom there is a note for the customer to check is order. I installed FireGento to solve a other Issue. But with the installation the note is displayed double. And more info is shown for the Products.
I erased the note from the backend now, so no note is displayed.
I need to get rid of the double entries and the into to the products. Also I would like to get rid of FireGento, without breaking the shop.

Comment: which version of magento you are using?

Comment: I'm using Magento 1.9.2.1

Comment: provide a screen shot of that section. I am not able to identify which section you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Found one ore a combination of ways to solve it.

First I deaktivated the Extension in the Backend
system -> Configuration -> Advanced / Advanced -> search for the extension and deaktivate it

Second I went to
app > etc > modules > Extension_Name.XML
searched for a line with 
`<active>true</active>`
and change to 
`<active>false</active>`

Third I deaktived the Cache of the Shop
System -> Cache Management

Now I could erase (I renamed) the extension Files. I always checked the Shop, to be sure its still working.

Hope that helps someone in future.